# Best practice on repurposing button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a relatively simple case where I want to repurpose a "Start" button with an "Abort" button after it is first clicked.

I'm wondering what is the best way to implement this button repurposing using XAML, hopefully declaratively rather than with a code-behind hack:

```
<DockPanel>
  <Button x:Name="btnStart">Start</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

I tried the following with using two distinct `Button`s and toggling the `Visibility` property of each but it does not reflow the layout within the `DockPanel`. I want the buttons to share the same layout space but mutually exclusively. This also has the problem where only the last element fills the dock panel and the first element is squished off to the left.

```
<DockPanel>
  <Button x:Name="btnStart">Start</Button>
  <Button x:Name="btnAbort" Visibility="Hidden">Abort</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

I prefer the two `Button` approach so that I can have separate `Click` event handlers. Please don't suggest naive solutions like dynamically adding/removing Button elements. I'd prefer a declarative approach if at all possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to set the `Visibility` property to `Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`? If you do that, the unused button should not use any layout space.

Comment: Collapsed doesn't do it either unfortunately. The Start button layout is still docked to the left.

Comment: Well actually, Collapsed puts me on the right track, but I still have the layout problem in the DockPanel.

Comment: I found my solution using a Grid instead of a DockPanel or StackPanel. Appreciate the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a viable option for you, you could try downloading the WPF toolkit and creating a single control with multiple states using the VisualStateManager.

Everything can be done declaratively in the XAML and switching between the States is fairly simple...especially if you're familiar at all with Silverlight development.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not being at all familiar enough with WPF or Silverlight leads me to believe this doesn't seem worth the time for such a simple case. Can you provide a quickie example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be snarky, but I wouldn't do it, unless you also change the visual state and look of the button to feel like something that would have that behavior, like an animated toggle switch or something. If the button launches a process which is slow running and you want to be able to abort it, I would think that (a) having a separate progress dialog showing the status and a cancellation option or (b) enabling that status and cancellation control in a different part of your window would be more consistent with other user interfaces. Also, accidental double clicks will immediately cancel the action, which might be odd.

Comment: The purpose of the button is to start/stop a background task. The rest of the UI surrounding the button is for displaying statistical information related to the background task. In this case it wouldn't make much sense to pop up a progress dialog since the entire point of the application is to serve the UI needs of this background task. Thanks for the UI suggestions.

Who double-clicks a button nowadays anyway? :P

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked assign a different command to the button and change the caption. Then when it is clicked it will goto a completely different handler in the code behind.